# Error net::err_unknown_url_scheme tel:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview, import

I buit an webview app with Android Studio and in my website i have a link like tel:0752118 when i press this link from app return eror net::err_unknown_url_scheme

This is my MainActivity.java

```js
  package totalonlinesrl.totalonline;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayout layoutProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        layoutProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        });
        if(isOnline()) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://total-online.eu/");
        } else {
            String summary = "<html><body><font color='red'>No Internet Connection</font></body></html>";
            webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            toast("No Internet Connection.");
        }
    }
    private void toast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }
}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: follow this link http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/09/17/fix-err_unknown_url_scheme-on-android-webview-for-telsmsgeoetc-links/

Answer (score 0):

If the links contain geographic locations, phone numbers, and email addresses, you can switch to the search screen and mail client using the code below.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        view.reload();
        return true;
    } else if (url.contains("mailto:")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else if(url.contains("geo:")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```